# Deleting item of listview from database but it is not properly deleting

Tags: android

Hello i am creating database application in which all records are displaying in listview from database and when user long press on listview selected item should be display from listview i have added ids to each item and i am deleting item by id which is selected from listview problem is that when item is deleted and i am insert new  item it's id is increased and it is not match to listview selected  item,please help me thanks in advance...

here is code of user longpress on listview

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            View v=findViewById(R.id.groupList);
            //activity.openContextMenu(v);

            helper.deleteName((arg2+1));
            c.requery();                
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and here is logic of deleting item from database

```
class DatabaseHelper{

    public void insertGroup(String name){
        db.execSQL("insert into GroupNames (names) values('"+name+"')");
    }

    public Cursor selectAll(){
        return db.rawQuery("select * from GroupNames", null);
    }

    public String getName(Cursor c){
        return c.getString(0);
    }

    public void deleteName(int i){

        c.moveToPosition(i);
        db.execSQL("delete from GroupNames where _id="+i);          
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a global variable COUNT and increment or decrement accoding to add or deleting rows.. (Its just my view)

Comment: you are mistaking position and id.

Comment: did u try Logging your code?

Comment: Are you using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

The `arg2` is NOT the ID of your item, take a look at [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) to understand what it is !

The `arg3` is NOT the ID of your item in the database, but the row ID of the Android ressource (i.e. R.id.xxx), so you can't just use the data given by the parameters of `onItemLongClick()`.

Knowing this, you can figure out that the line `helper.deleteName((arg2+1));` is not correct and doesn't mean anything : `arg2+1` means absolutely nothing for your database.

A solution (not the best I think), should be to include an **invisible** field in your item view, storing the actual `_id` field of your database. Then, when a long press is detected, you get back this value and pass it to `helper.deleteName()`.

Comment: i did not make out perfectly can u explain me

Comment: ask your question, I will answer you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should Log your code for your understating,what data going where?

and here in below code, when i delete something i give response back so that i understand whether its deleted or not.

```
 public int deleteAlarm(long unique_id) {
              db = this.getWritableDatabase();
              int delete = db.delete(ALARM_TABLE_NAME, "unique_id=" + unique_id, null);
              db.close();
              return delete;
        }
```